# Google map on phonegap project

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova, maps

I am finishing an app for iphone/android in which I display a map (google maps) with my position and a lot of pins nearby.

My problem is that the first time it works perfect and the second time I open it, it centers it wrong and it only shows a part of the map, the top left part and only like the first quarter of the map is visible.
Did someone have this issue? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you provide some code. I've faced same when i tried to reuse the division with data role
try creating new request each time you wish to see map

Comment: Did that work for you? I just want to rewrite the pins and not the whole map again.

Comment: yes it worked!! if you are using div:datarole thn stop tht and either do logic on same page or create another page

Comment: I moved the map_canvas out of the div with data-role ... still no dice. I still get only half the map shown when I return to the page. 

<div id="map_canvas" style="height:240px;"></div>

<div data-role="content">
 ... content stuff ..
</div

Answer (score 0):

For me, the following worked:

After creating the 'map' object, do:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
       google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
       map.setCenter(mapCenter);
    });
```

This is not my solution. I found it somewhere here on SO, but I just can't seem to find the same post again.